# Unable to reliably hide and reveal element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to have some text appear when an icon is clicked, and  disappear when the space bar is pressed. At the moment it consistently appears but will only disappear if the page is clicked before pressing space. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function solution() {
  $("#solution").removeClass("solutionHide");
  $("#solution").html(originalAlg);
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      $("#solution").addClass("solutionHide");
  }
}
```

```css
#solution {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 5px green;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.solutionHide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='solution' class='solutionHide'></h1>

<input id='cubeIcon' type='image' src='cubeicon.png' onclick='solution();' />
```

Comment: What is `timerStatus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function solution() {
originalAlg = "SOME TEXT";
  $("#solution").removeClass("solutionHide");
  $("#solution").html(originalAlg);
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      $("#solution").addClass("solutionHide");
  }
}
```

```css
#solution {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 5px green;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.solutionHide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='solution' class='solutionHide'></h1>

<!--<input id='cubeIcon' type='image' src='cubeicon.png' onclick='solution();' />-->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="solution();">Submit Query</a>
```

Comment: originalAlg is defined earlier on in my code. In your code, the issue still remains that you have to click off of the image before pressing space to make the text disappear. I apologise that I didn't explain the issue properly enough in my original post.

Comment: ok, i think when you click on button your cursor still not changed untill i have click outside the button.

Comment: Change element to anker tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you test it directly in the browser the space key works. In snippets tools like here or jsfiddle the output comes in an iframe. Then you have to focus the window.

You can use `window.focus()` to do this manualy

```js
const originalAlg = 'BLUB';
window.focus();

function solution() {
  $("#solution").removeClass("solutionHide");
  $("#solution").html(originalAlg);
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      solution();
  }
}
```

```css
#solution {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 5px green;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.solutionHide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='solution' class='solutionHide'></h1>

<input id='cubeIcon' type='image' src='cubeicon.png' onclick='solution();' />
```